# Points of Intersection of Curves

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-geometry

There are $4$ distinct parabolas, $5$ distinct circles and $3$ distinct lines in the $x-y$ plane. Find the maximum possible value of the number of their points of intersection.

My Attempt at the Question:
I first to try and figure out the maximum number of points of intersection. For that I figured that parabola and circle intersect at max. $4$ points. And straight line will intersect the circle and parabola at $4$ distinct points. But this lead me nowhere.

Answer (score 1):

Use the fact that 2 parabolae intersect at 4 points.So does the circles.
Generalising it,
n parabolas will intersect (maximum)on $4(^nC_2)$ points.
Thus total =
$4\times(^4C_2) + 2\times(^5C_2) + 1\times(^3C_2) + 4\times(5\times4) + 2\times(4\times3) +2\times(5\times3)
= 181$ points.
Your doubts about it are most welcome!

Comment: The answer in the key us given as 181

Comment: @user36160 , seems did some calculation mistake.

Comment: And please properly format and explain the answer

Comment: From starting, point of intersections of P with P, C with C, L with L, P with C, P with L, C with L.

Comment: Got it.. thanks

Comment: the circles only intersect at 2 points. @8hantanu in your answer you mentioned "so does the circles". you are wrong there

Answer (score 1):

First we find the kinds of intersection that take place b/w the lines, circles and parabolas, which are as follows:-

1. Parabola with a parabola
2. Parabola with a circle
3. Parabola with a line
4. Circle with a circle
5. Circle with a line
6. Line with a line

Now, lets count the maximum number of point of intersection in each of the above cases and consequently count the maximum number of intersections that cantake place given that there are $4$ distinct parabolas, $5$ distinct circles and $3$ distinct lines:-

**CASE 1:- Intersection of two parabolas**

[image: intersection of parabola with a parabola]

As we can see in the above image there are maximum $4$ possible points of intersection for two distinct parabolas. Since there are $4$ distinct parabolas hence there are maximum $4\cdot\binom{4}{2}$ maximum distinct point of intersections.

$\therefore$ Maximum number of points of intersection of $4$ distinct parabola$=4\cdot\displaystyle\binom{4}{2}=24$

**CASE 2:- Intersection of parabola with a circle**

[image: Intersection of parabola with a circle]

As can be seen in the above image there are at max. $4$ distinct points of intersection of a parabola and a circle.

Ways to select a parabola and a circle$= \displaystyle\binom{4}{1}\cdot\binom{5}{1}$

$\therefore$ Max. no. of distinct points of intersection$=4\cdot\displaystyle\binom{4}{1}\cdot\binom{5}{1}=80$

**CASE 3:- Intersection of a parabola with a line**

[image: Intersection of parabola with a line]

As can be seen in the above image there can be max. $2$ distinct points of intersection b/w a line and a parabola.

Ways to select a parabola and a line $=\displaystyle\binom{4}{1}\cdot\binom{3}{1}$

$\therefore$ Max. no. of distinct points of intersection$=2\cdot\displaystyle\binom{4}{1}\cdot\binom{3}{1}=24$

**CASE 4:- Intersection of two circles**

[image: Intersection of a circle with a circle]

As can be seen in the above image there can be max. $2$ distinct points of intersection b/w two circles.

Ways to select two circles $=\displaystyle\binom{5}{2}$

$\therefore$ Max. no. of distinct points of intersection$=2\cdot\displaystyle\binom{5}{2}=20$

**CASE 5:- Intersection of a circle with a line**

[image: Intersection of a circle with a line]

As can be seen in the above image there can be max. $2$ distinct points of intersection b/w a line and a circle.

Ways to select a circle and a line $=\displaystyle\binom{5}{1}\cdot\binom{3}{1}$

$\therefore$ Max. no. of distinct points of intersection$=2\cdot\displaystyle\binom{5}{1}\binom{3}{1}=30$

**CASE 6:- Intersection of two lines**

[image]

As can be seen in the above image there can be max. $1$ distinct points of intersection b/w two lines.

Ways to select two lines $=\displaystyle\binom{3}{2}$

$\therefore$ Max. no. of distinct points of intersection$=1\cdot\displaystyle\binom{3}{2}=3$

Since all the above cases are disjoint, and when anyone of them happens an intersection takes place, hence the total no of intersections are the sum of all the disjoint events.

Hence, total number of points of intersection is given by

$$4\cdot\displaystyle\binom{4}{2}+ 4\cdot\displaystyle\binom{4}{1}\cdot\binom{5}{1} + 2\cdot\displaystyle\binom{4}{1}\cdot\binom{3}{1} + 2\cdot\displaystyle\binom{5}{2} + 2\cdot\displaystyle\binom{5}{1}\binom{3}{1} + 1\cdot\displaystyle\binom{3}{2}\\
=24+80+24+20+30+3=\boxed{181}$$

Comment: Got it.. Thanks

Comment: But I can not understand how you are being so sure that no two intersection point will coincide. The intersection point of a circle and a straight line may coincide with the same of a circle and circle.

Comment: @sani But the OP asked for the maximum number of intersections.....so if we consider coincidence of intersection points then that won't give the max number of intersection points.